How can I enable swagger in internal development environmensts that is not local host
I have a .NET 8 WEB API, which has been dockerized and running inside of a container. This container is pushed the the Azure ACR and deployed on to Azure AKS.
Functionality wise this is working alright but I would like to enable Swagger UI if someone wants to directly test this out without having to run it through visual studio.
Swagger UI works fine when I run it through Visual studio.
To achieve this I added this change from the code
var internalEnv = app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Internal_Environment") is "Development";
`if (internalEnv)
{
 Console.Write("Internal is true");

 app.UseSwagger();
 app.UseSwaggerUI();
 }
`

In the deployment yaml file that I use to deploy this to the AKS cluster (development that is) I added this
`        env:
        - name: Internal_Environment
          value: "Development"`

When I check the container log I can see the line "Internal is true" which means app.UseSwagger and app.UseSwaggerUI is called. But the issue is I cannot find the correct url to access the swagger UI.
Typically an endpoint would be specified as follows (a hello end point for example),
http://test-dev.abcword.com/api/registration/hello => This works fine
So I tried accessing swagger through
http://test-dev.abcword.com/api/registration/swagger/index.html but this gives a 404.
The application is a part of a microservices solution
Any help is much appreciated
Tried adding an environment variable and enabling swagger when that environment variable is present

The correct swagger-ui url should be http://test-dev.abcword.com/swagger/index.html, instead of http://test-dev.abcword.com/api/registration/swagger/index.html. Try it and let me know the test result.

Hi Jason, I have an ingress controller as well, should I pass in some swagger specific stuff there?

Hi Devin, does the url I provided is working or not ?

UPDATE
var internalEnv = app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Internal_Environment") == "Development";

if (internalEnv)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Internal is true");
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "api/registration/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/registration/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = "api/registration/swagger";
    });
}



http://test-dev.abcword.com/api/registration/swagger/index.html but this gives a 404.

The correct url shoud be http://test-dev.abcword.com/swagger/index.html or http://test-dev.abcword.com/swagger.
And we also can change the default url by using RoutePrefix. Here is the sample code.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;// Set Swagger UI at apps root
});


Thank you for the answer
Unfortunately I get an 404. I think there is an issue with ingress routing that I have setup. Let me attach the ingress file as well, incase this is something you might have encountered before

@Devin Waiting for your update.

Just updated it with proper formatting

Hi @Devin, After my investigation, the update code should works for you, please try it, I am waiting for your update.
